# how to get value of an item in array with useFieldArray

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

Here's the field array initialization:

```
const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
        control, // control props comes from useForm (optional: if you are using FormContext)
        name: "items", // unique name for your Field Array
        rules: {
            required: "Please append at least 1 item"
        }
    });
```

and the dynamic form:

```
{fields.map((field, i) =>
                                <div key={field.id} tw="grid grid-rows-2 grid-cols-[64px_100px_100px_auto] tablet:flex tablet:flex-row gap-x-6 gap-x-4 gap-y-4 mb-4">
                                    <div tw="flex flex-col col-span-4 tablet:w-[220px]">
                                        <label htmlFor="itemName" tw="text-secondary">Item Name</label>
                                        <StyledInput type="text" id="itemName" {...register(`item.${i}.name`, { required: "Can't be empty" })} />
                                        <Error>{errors?.['item']?.[i]?.['name']?.['message']}</Error>
                                    </div>
                                    <div tw="flex flex-col row-start-2 col-start-1 tablet:w-12">
                                        **<label htmlFor="itemsQuantity" tw="text-secondary">Qty.</label>
                                        <StyledInput type="text" id="itemsQuantity" {...register(`item.${i}.quantity`, { valueAsNumber: true }, { required: "Can't be empty" })} />**
                                        <Error>{errors?.['item']?.[i]?.['quantity']?.['message']}</Error>
                                    </div>
                                    <div tw="flex flex-col row-start-2 col-start-2 tablet:w-20">
                                        **<label htmlFor="itemPrice" tw="text-secondary">Price</label>
                                        <StyledInput type="text" id="itemPrice" {...register(`item.${i}.price`, { valueAsNumber: true }, { required: "Can't be empty" })} />**
                                        <Error>{errors?.['item']?.[i]?.['price']?.['message']}</Error>
                                    </div>
                                    <div tw="flex flex-col row-start-2 col-start-3 tablet:w-20">
                                        <label htmlFor="itemPrice" tw="text-secondary">Total</label>
                                        <StyledField>{Intl.NumberFormat('en-GB', { style: "currency", currency: 'GBP' }).format(`item.${i}.price` * `item.${i}.quantity`)}</StyledField>
                                    </div>
                                    <div onClick={() => remove(i)} tw="flex flex-col pt-4 row-start-2 col-start-4 tablet:w-auto place-content-center cursor-pointer">
                                        <Image src="/assets/icon-delete.svg" width={12} height={16} alt="recyclingBin" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>)}
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how to extract the values from the bolded parts (quantity and price) so I can get their products and put it in the next div.

> 

```
<StyledField>{Intl.NumberFormat('en-GB', { style: "currency", currency: 'GBP' }).format(**`item[i].price` * `item[i].quantity`**)}</StyledField>
```

The bolded part is my attempt at solving the problem.  The compiler throws an error saying that "item is not defined"

Any help will be appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Beside using getValues(), you can also use watch function that acquired from useForm() function https://www.react-hook-form.com/api/useform/watch/

1. define a watch constant for the field array

   ```
   const watchItems = watch('items')
   ```
2. use the watch value in the dynamic field

   ```
   <StyledField>{Intl.NumberFormat('en-GB', { style: "currency", currency: 'GBP' }).format(watchItems[i].price) * watchItems[i].quantity)}</StyledField>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Got it.

I had to use getValue() to extract the values I needed.

```
<StyledField>{Intl.NumberFormat('en-GB', { style: "currency", currency: 'GBP' }).format(getValues(`item.${i}.price`) * getValues(`item.${i}.quantity`))}</StyledField>
```